# How to create MySQL prepared statement string without connecting to database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, stringbuilder

How do I create a mysql prepared statement 'string' without actually connecting to MySQL. I want to utilize PDO's bindparam to generate a 'mysql string'.

I just need the mysql string. I don't want to do inline variables on the mysql string because it's messy and hard to maintain.

If this can't be done. Do you know any  (PHP) string builder library that build a MySQL string?

Comment: No possible, if without connection, there is no clue to determine what of parameters to be bind/prepared

Comment: Even inline variables on the mysql string requires MySQL connection because of `mysql_real_escape_string`. In order to properly escape variables this function needs to know connection encoding information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does [PDOStatement->debugDumpParams](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php) give you some help?

Comment: but you need a $dbh object which initializes a connection

Comment: Yes, but if you don't have a connection, you have to create your own  parser to detect the error of your 'MySQL string', why not just let the database do it for you?